# Error while defining a \newcommand using xcolor package

Tags: colors, macros, latex, overleaf

I am required to show the changes while I am editing a Latex document. So I have defined some colours variables as follows:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\color{NavyBlue}{{}ADDED: #1}}}
\newcommand{\deleted}[1]{{\color{red}{DELETED: \sout{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{{\color{ForestGreen}{[#1]}}}
```

This would then be used in the document as follows:

```
\begin{document}

Hi
I am showing that \deleted{I am deleting my old words}, \added{adding some new words} and \comment{offering some comments.}


\end{document}
```

This is creating errors, can anyone plz help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavyBlue`, `ForrestGreen` etc. are normally not defined. You need to use the `dvipsnames` option if you want to use such names.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand{\added}[1]{{\color{NavyBlue}{{}ADDED: #1}}}
\newcommand{\deleted}[1]{{\color{red}{DELETED: \sout{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{{\color{ForestGreen}{[#1]}}}

\begin{document}

Hi
I am showing that \deleted{I am deleting my old words}, \added{adding some new words} and \comment{offering some comments.}


\end{document}
```

[image]